# How replace a table view by a collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tableview, xlpagertabstrip

I want to replace a table view by a collection view, the table view is inside a   tab from XLPagerTabStrip.

I already tried to replace some things but I get some errors, can someone put me on the right direction ?

```
import UIKit
import XLPagerTabStrip

class BooksChildViewController: UITableViewController, 
IndicatorInfoProvider {

    let cellIdentifier = "postCell"
    var blackTheme = false
    var itemInfo = IndicatorInfo(title: "Livros")

    init(style: UITableViewStyle, itemInfo: IndicatorInfo) {
        self.itemInfo = itemInfo
        super.init(style: style)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    }

    // MARK: - IndicatorInfoProvider

    func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController:
PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
        return itemInfo
    }

}
```

Comment: If you need a Collectionview, why did you create a UITableViewController? Do you need to use both in your UI? You should inherit your Viewcontroller from simply UIViewController and make it adapt to both TableView and CollectionView delegates/datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `BooksChildViewController` should inherit UICollectionViewController instead of `UITableViewController`.

Also, you need modify your `init()` . `UICollectionViewController` can be initializer with a `UICollectionViewLayout` instead with a style like `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Yes, actually I tried this but it says: Argument labels '(style:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: I think it's because the constructor of the class UICollectionView don't have a "style" parameter.